# Show $X^2=n(\sum_{j=1}^{c}\sum_{i=1}^{r}\frac{n_{ij}^2}{r_ic_j}-1)$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

Suppose that the entries in a contingency table that appear in row $i$ and column $j$ are denoted $n_{ij}$, for $i=1,2,...,r$ and $j=1,2,...,c$; that the row and column totals are denoted $r_i$, for $i=1,2,...,r$ and $c_j$, for $j=1,2,...,c$; and that the total sample size is $n$. It was also given that $\widehat{E(n_{ij})}=\frac{r_ic_j}{n}$. Show that

$$X^2=\sum_{j=1}^{c}\sum_{i=1}^{r}\frac{[n_{ij}-\widehat{E(n_{ij})}]^2}{\widehat{E(n_{ij})}}=n\Big(\sum_{j=1}^{c}\sum_{i=1}^{r}\frac{n_{ij}^2}{r_ic_i}-1\Big).$$

We see that 
\begin{align}
X^2 &= \sum_{j=1}^{c}\sum_{i=1}^{r}\frac{[n_{ij}-\widehat{E(n_{ij})}]^2}{\widehat{E(n_{ij})}}\\
    &= n\Big(\sum_{j=1}^{c}\sum_{i=1}^{r}\frac{n_{ij}^2-n_{ij}\frac{r_ic_j}{n}+\frac{r_i^2c_j^2}{n^2}}{r_ic_j}\Big)\\
    &= n\Big(\sum_{j=1}^{c}\sum_{i=1}^{r}\frac{n_{ij}^2}{r_ic_j}-\frac{nn_{ij}}{n}+\frac{r_ic_j}{n^2}\Big)\\
    &= n\Big(\sum_{j=1}^{c}\sum_{i=1}^{r}\frac{n_{ij}^2}{r_ic_j}+\frac{1}{n}\Big(\widehat{E(n_{ij})}-n_{ij}\Big)\Big).
\end{align}
I thought $\frac{1}{n}\Big(\widehat{E(n_{ij})}-n_{ij}\Big)$ would be zero... what is wrong?

Comment: There is no reason to think the expected value would be exactly equal to the observed value for any n$_i$$_j$.

Comment: Right, I assumed that the expected value was unbiased since the bias was not given. Can I answer this without any information about the bias of the given expected value?

Comment: Bias is not the issue.  The expected value is an average.  If the long run average is equal to the parameter the expected value is unbiased.  It has nothing to do with what the observed values are.

Comment: I meant to refer to the estimate of the expected value (not an actual expected value so it has a bias). Glen is leading me to my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your derivation you didn't correctly expand the square.
2. The term at the end that you thought would be zero will not be zero.

   - Under the null it has an expectation of zero but we're not taking expectations here
   - however (and more importantly for your derivation) the sum over i and j of all such terms *will* be zero (but note that because of point 1., that cancellation won't cancel the whole thing after the first term because you didn't expand the quadratic correctly).

Comment: I recalculated the expansion but did not find my error. What simple thing am I missing?

Comment: Forget the problem and look at a simpler question -- what do you get when you expand $(a-b)^2$?